# How can I count the number of different characters in a file?

Tags: command-line, files, text-processing

I would need a program, that outputs the number of the different characters in a file. Example:

```
> stats testfile
' ': 207
'e': 186
'n': 102
```

Exists any tool, that do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following should work:

```
$ sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' text.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

First, we insert a newline after every character, putting each character on its own line. Then we sort it.  Then we use the uniq command to remove the duplicates, prefixing each line with the number of occurrences of that character.

To sort the list by frequency, pipe this all into `sort -nr`.

Comment: On sed for Mac OS X it's `sed 's/\(.\)/\1\'$'\n/g' text.txt`

Comment: Very nice, but unfortunately it does not work correctly if the text contains Unicode (utf8) characters. There may be a way to make `sed` do this, but Jacob [Vlijm's Python solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/593503) worked well for me.

Answer (score 15):

[Steven's solution is a good, simple one.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5010/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-different-characters-in-a-file/5011#5011) It's not so performant for very large files (files that don't fit comfortably in about half your RAM) because of the sorting step. Here's an awk version. It's also a little more complicated because it tries to do the right thing for a few special characters (newlines, `'`, `\`, `:`).

```
awk '
  {for (i=1; i<=length; i++) ++c[substr($0,i,1)]; ++c[RS]}
  function chr (x) {return x=="\n" ? "\\n" : x==":" ? "\\072" :
                           x=="\\" || x=="'\''" ? "\\" x : x}
  END {for (x in c) printf "'\''%s'\'': %d\n", chr(x), c[x]}
' | sort -t : -k 2 -r | sed 's/\\072/:/'
```

Here's a Perl solution on the same principle. Perl has the advantage of being able to sort internally. Also this will correctly not count an extra newline if the file does not end in a newline character.

```
perl -ne '
  ++$c{$_} foreach split //;
  END { printf "'\''%s'\'': %d\n", /[\\'\'']/ ? "\\$_" : /./ ? $_ : "\\n", $c{$_}
        foreach (sort {$c{$b} <=> $c{$a}} keys %c) }'
```

Comment: +1 for not doing that horrible sort

Answer (score 1):

A slow but relatively memory-friendly version, using ruby. About a dozen MB of RAM, regardless of input size.

```
# count.rb
ARGF.
  each_char.
  each_with_object({}) {|e,a| a[e] ||= 0; a[e] += 1}.
  each {|i| puts i.join("\t")}

ruby count.rb < input.txt
t       20721
d       20628
S       20844
k       20930
h       20783
... etc
```

Answer (score 1):

More obvious solution that I use to count occurrences of characters in a file:

```bsh
cat filename | grep -o . | sort | uniq -c | sort -bnr
```

pipes output to `grep`, which then prints every char on one line `| sort` then reprints each char the amount of times it shows up in the file `| uniq` counts the amount of occurrences `| sort -n` sorts that input again, by number

With a file that contains the text "Peanut butter and jelly caused the elderly lady to think about her past."

Output:

```
     13  
      9 e
      7 d
      5 s
      5 a
      4 o
      4 h

... and more
```

The first line would be the amount of space characters in the file, you can filter that out if you like using `tr -d " "`

Answer (score 1):

Simple and relatively performant:

```bash
fold -c1 testfile.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Just tell `fold` to wrap (i.e. insert newline) after every 1 character.

---

---

How tested:

- a 128MB all-ASCII file

  - Created by `find . -type f -name '*.[hc]' -exec cat {} >> /tmp/big.txt \;` in a few codebases.
- workstation-class machine (real iron, not VM)
- environment variable `LC_ALL=C`

---

Runtimes in descending order:

- Steven's `sed|sort|uniq` solution (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5011/427210): 102.5 sec
- my `fold|sort|uniq` solution: 59.3 sec
- my `fold|sort|uniq` solution, with `--buffer-size=12G` option given to `sort`: 38.9 sec
- my `fold|sort|uniq` solution, with `--buffer-size=12G` and `--stable` options given to `sort`: 37.9 sec
- Giles's `perl` solution (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5013/427210): 34.0 sec

  - Winner!  Like they say, the fastest sort is *not having to sort*.   `:-)`

Comment: `The GNU implementation of fold currently only works correctly with single-byte characters.`

See [Stéphane's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486428/301396)

Comment: When speaking of multibyte encodings, helps to distinguish between fixed-width and variable-width encodings.  With fixed-width encodings, instead of the `-c`/`--characters` flag you could simply give `fold(1)` the `-b`/`--bytes` flag: `-b2` with UCS-2, `-b4` with UCS-4 _(also known as UTF-32)_.

Comment: In fact, `-c`/`--characters` appears to be a GNU extension; the POSIX spec of `fold(1)` (ref https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fold.html) does not have it.