# unicode safe alternative for fold

Tags: sed, fold

I'm using `fold -w 3` to split a line into multiple 3 chars long, however with the GNU implementation, it does not work for text with multi-byte characters it seems.

How can I achieve the above with `sed`?

I've come up with `sed -r 's/^(.{0,3})(.*)/\1\n\2/g'` however this only does a single replacement:

```
echo "111222333444555666" | sed -r 's/^(.{0,3})(.*)/\1\n\2/g' 
111
222333444555666
```

---

Additional examples:

```
echo "ĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄ" | sed -r 's/^(.{0,3})(.*)/\1\n\2/g' 
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄ
```

And `fold` with it's corrupting behavior:

```
echo "ĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄ" | fold -w 3                         
Ą�
�Ą
Ą�
�Ą
Ą�
```

Comment: `echo "ĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄ" | fold -b6`

Comment: @Jesse_b that'll only work for strings with all 2-byte characters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short **`grep`** approach:

```
echo "ĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄ" | grep -Eo '.{1,3}'
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄ
```

---

To retain only 3-char sequences: `... | grep -Eo '.{3}'`

Answer (score 6):

Note that the issue is not with the Unicode character set, but with characters that are encoded on 2 or more bytes (as well as characters that have a width other than one cell).

UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode where characters U+0080 to U+10FFFFF are encoded on 2 or more bytes. Unicode characters U+0000 to U+007F are the same as in ASCII and in UTF-8 are encoded on a single byte (same as in ASCII) and are not a problem here.

There are other encodings of the Unicode charset (like iso8859-1, single-byte but limited to characters U+0000 to U+00FF, or GB18030, multi-byte), and there are other non-Unicode character sets with multi-byte encodings.

You can tell what character encoding is used in your locale with the `locale charmap` command.

The GNU implementation of `fold` currently only works correctly with single-byte characters. The `fold` of most other systems don't have that problem. Many can even handle characters with zero or double display width.

The busybox implementation of `fold` has supported UTF-8 (not other multi-byte charmaps though) since 2010.

- On FreeBSD or Solaris:

  ```
    $ echo $'a\u0301bcde' | fold -w3
    ábc
    de
  ```
- with busybox fold:

  ```
    $ echo $'a\u0301bcde' | busybox fold -w3
    áb
    cde
  ```
- with GNU fold:

  ```
    $ echo $'a\u0301bcde' | fold -w3
    á
    bcd
    e
  ```

U+0301 is a combining acute accent. It has a null width and in UTF-8 is encoded on 2 bytes (0xcc 0x81). So, that `á` (`$'a\u0301'`) is one grapheme cluster of width 1 made of 2 characters encoded on 3 bytes, hence the 3 different behaviours, the most correct of which is FreeBSD/Solaris' here.

With GNU `grep` built with PCRE support and in a UTF-8 locale and with UTF-8 input:

```
grep -Po '\X{1,3}'
```

Which `o`utputs all the sequences of 1 to 3 (as many as possible) e`X`tended grapheme clusters on each line of the input may given you better results for cases like the above where you have combining marks combined with single-width characters.

It won't help if there are double-width characters or zero-with characters not combined with single-width ones or there are control characters like TAB, CR, BS.

Comment: [suckless fold from sbase](https://git.suckless.org/sbase/file/fold.c.html) also handles UTF-8, but behaves like busybox fold with the example from this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using sed:

```
$ echo "ĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄ" | sed 's/.../&\n/g'
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄ
```

Or more general solution(s) (easier to define the number of characters):

```
sed    's/.\{3\}/&\n/g'             # Using BRE (basic) syntax
sed -E 's/.{3}/&\n/g'               # Using ERE (extended) syntax.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
echo "ĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄ" | sed -r 's/(.{0,3}){1}/&\n/g' 
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
```

Comment: That seems more complicated than it needs to be - you don't seem to be actually *using* the capture group, and isn't `<thing>{1}` equivalent to just `<thing>`?

Comment: `(.{0,3}){1}` should be `.{1,3}`

Answer (score 0):

Just because...

```
$ echo "ĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄ" | gawk '{$1=$1} 1' FPAT=".{,3}" OFS="\n"
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄĄ
ĄĄ
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a POSIX solution:

```sh
awk '{gsub(/.{5}/, "&\n")} 1'
```

Interestingly, the Awk solution is more performant than fold.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187078/-/23599010